# How to import existing node.js module into Intellij IDEA?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

I have an existing Node.js codebase, forked from GitHub. Now I want to import it to the Intellij IDEA 13 (ultimate version, which supports Node.js). When I simply try to import the project from the root folder of my existing code, IDEA doesn't add the 'lib' folder, where all the sources are. It should be simple, but I cannot figure it out. Any hints?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Well, I've figured out a workaround, but not sure if it's the best solution. One can just create a new project of type "Web", and point it to the directory containing the module's sources. Then IDEA understands the whole structure, and you can create run configurations with Node.js.

In order to get additional Node features, like Intellisense for standard Node APIs, you'll still want to configure the project to be a Node project:

1. Open the *Preferences* window
2. Click *Languages & Frameworks → Node.js and NPM*
3. In the section *Coding Assistance* you'll see if *Node.js Core library is [not] enabled*. If it *is* enabled, there's nothing more to do. If not click the *Enable* button
4. Leave *For the whole project* checked, and click *Configure*
5. The text should now change to *Node.js Core library is enabled*.

Comment: bit more info. File -> New Project -> Static Web -> Static Web (next) -> project location (browse to root folder for the codebase)(finish)

Comment: This partly answers the question.  You still want to configure the project to be a Node project so you can get additional Node features - like intellisense for standard node APIs.

Comment: @TonyO'Hagan, can you add how to configure it to be a node project?

Comment: @bschandramohan I have made an edit suggestion to the answer which includes that information. In short, you have to go to _Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM_, and click _Enable_.

Comment: 2022, and still needed to use this, but it worked!

Answer (score 4):

Another workaround:

If you have a version controlled Node app with no local changes, you could also create a new project of type "Node.js and NPM", point that to the directory. Then just use any standard settings.

After the project is created, you can just revert the files overwritten by IDEA (e.g. app.js and package.json), delete any new directories and files, and you will get the additional Node features in your project.

Answer (score 4):

Intellij 15 Professional Edition:

Import a new project -> Select the base folder of the project -> choose import form existing source.

When Intellij is done it wont look correct so do the following:

1) Project Structure CMD + ;

2) Go to Modules

3) Add a new module and select Node/Npm (if you dont have it then add a new plugin)

4) Point the source of the project to the base folder and click apply.

Comment: **!!!Warning!!!** if you point this to an existing project (and chose react) it will delete all of your files including the .git directory.

Answer (score 0):

If IntelliJ doesn't recognize a node.js project you should add the directory as a new module.

```
File -> New -> Module
```